# auditd rule without specified permission

Tags: linux, audit

When creating an auditd rule in Linux, what is the behaviour if no permissions are specified?

ie

`-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k shadow`

will monitor for new writes or changed attributes.

But if I wrote it as:

`-w /etc/shadow -k shadow`

then is there a default permission? or does it imply that all permissions will be monitored ie rwax?

Answer (score 0):

Without -p:

The -w option tells audit to add a watch to the file specified, in this case /etc/shadow. All system calls requesting access permissions to this file are analyzed

https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-audit-comp.html#sec-audit-rules

---

Using -p:

This rule adds a watch to the /etc directory and applies permission filtering for read and execute access to this directory (-p rx). Any system call requesting any of these two permissions is analyzed.